# getting wrong values while joining tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

MY tables are

Parent WO

```
WO     PRICE
1      1790    
1      9
```

Child WO

```
WO     PRICE
1      200    
1      400    
1      600
1      100
```

I am trying to do this

```
Select  sum(p.price), SUM(c.price) from Parent_WO p
left outer join Child_WO c
on p.WO= c.WO  
group by p.WO
```

I am getting the wrong value for the p.price. I am getting 7196 when it should by 1796. It's multipe the total of the parent WO with the 4 child WO.

Comment: Why do you have four duplicate rows in the second table?  If you fix the data, you'll probably fix the query.

Comment: Its not duplicate rows, they have more different columns which did not write.

Comment: When you join two rows in parent and four rows in child with the same WO you get 2*4 rows before joining. It's an m-to-n-join instead of 1-to-n or 1-to-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the aggregation *before* doing the `sum()`:

```
Select coalesce(p.wo, c.wo) as wo, sum(p.price), SUM(c.price)
from (select p.wo, sum(p.price) as parent_price
      from Parent_WO p
      group by p.wo
     ) p full outer join
     (select c.wo, sum(c.price) as child_price
      from Child_WO c
      group by c.wo
     ) c
     on p.WO = c.WO ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using 2 [CTE's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx); calculate `Parent` price in one CTE and `Child` price in another CTE and join the results:

```
with parent_sum as (
  select
    wo
    ,SUM(price) as ParentSUM
  from parent_wo
  group by wo
)
,child_sum as (
  select
    wo
    ,SUM(price) as ChildSUM
  from child_wo
  group by wo
)
select
  p.wo
  ,ParentSUM
  ,ChildSUM
from parent_sum p
left join child_sum c
  on p.wo = c.wo
```